# Como transformar uma lista String em uma lista Float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se eu rodar esse código, ela dará uma lista em string:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fazendo assim com que eu não consiga fazer a média dos números corretamente (já que está em string). O que posso fazer para que o número seja impresso em float/int?

Esse "erro" acontece só com o Python.3x? O que aconteceria se eu migrasse para o 2x.? Ele imprimiria em float?

```
   vet_aluno = [0]*2
for i in range(2):
    vet_aluno[i] = input ("Digite o nome do(a) aluno(a): ")

vet_nota1 = [0]*2
for k in range(2):
    vet_nota1[k] = input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[0]) + ": ")


vet_nota2 = [0]*2
for a in range(2):
    vet_nota2[a] = input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[1]) + ": ")

#Calculando a média
media1 = media(vet_nota1[0],vet_nota1[1])
media2 = media(vet_nota2[0],vet_nota2[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Python3, quando você usa a função input para pedir um input do usuário, ela retorna sempre uma string.
Se você quiser pode transformar a string em float, da seguinte maneira:

```
vet_nota1 = [0]*2
for k in range(2):
    vet_nota1[k] = float( input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[0]) + ": "))

vet_nota2 = [0]*2
for a in range(2):
    vet_nota2[a] = float( input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[1]) + ": "))
```

Porém, fazendo apenas isso, você estará confiando que o usuário vai sempre digitar uma string que pode ser transformada num float.
Caso o usuário digite qualquer outra coisa, como 'Teste', ao ser perguntado da nota, haverá uma exceção do tipo ValueError e seu programa será finalizado.

---

Já no Python2, existem 2 funções para pedir input do usuário: a input e a raw_input.

A raw_input funciona como a input do Python3, apenas lhe retorna a string que foi digitada.
Já a input tenta interpretar o que foi digitado pelo usuário como uma expressão em Python. Então, caso ele digitasse algo no formato de um float, ela já lhe retornaria o input como float, não como string.

Em Python2, você poderia ter escrito o seguinte programa:

```
vet_aluno = [0]*2
for i in range(2):
    vet_aluno[i] = raw_input("Digite o nome do(a) aluno(a) {}: ".format(i))

vet_nota1 = [0]*2
for k in range(2):
    vet_nota1[k] = input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[0]) + ": ")

vet_nota2 = [0]*2
for a in range(2):
    vet_nota2[a] = input("Digite a nota de " + str(vet_aluno[1]) + ": ")
```

Comment: Nesse caso seria mais conveniente e prático usar o Python2?

Comment: Os dois são equivalentes nesse ponto. Em Python3 você também pode facilmente interpretar o input como float, como foi mostrado, e caso o usuário não digite um float no Python2, você também terá problemas caso não verifique que o que foi digitado é realmente o float, então isso não deve ser critério pra decidir entre um e outro. O melhor seria usar Python3 sempre que possível, visto que é a versão mais recente. Cada vez mais gente vai parar de suportar o Python2 no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dollar = float(soup.find_all('p')[2].get_text().split()[9][:-1].replace(',', '.'))
```